# Magento 2 - Move swatch options after product name in product details page

Tags: magento2, swatches

I want to move my `swatch option` after `product name`. If anyone have idea how to do?

Please let me know.

Comment: Swatch options must be within the product add to cart form. if you move swatch options outside the form, product will not adding to cart properly.

Comment: check with your catalog_product_view.xml

Answer (score 0):

You can't move `swatch option` up since doing it will push it outside the form and you won't be able to add product to cart. However, you can move everything above the `swatch option` into the form, below the `swatch option`

If you're using the default theme, you can move them as below:

> app/code/Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view_type_configurable.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <move element="product.info.price" destination="product.info.options.wrapper"/>
        <move element="product.info.review" destination="product.info.options.wrapper" before="product.info.price"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

Result:

[image]